# Hover on column and rows, with multiple background colors

Tags: html, css, styles, stylesheet, css-tables

I know this can be done with rows, but I haven't been able to make it also work for columns. I need to be able to color code my columns, but keep the same hover color across all columns. Below is the code I have so far, I need to color the background on the 1st column grey, and leave everything else the same white. While keeping the same hover color across all rows and columns. Hope that makes sense!

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/fazulk/pen/LzvKPo)

```css
.grey-column {
  background-color: grey;
}

.data-table {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-width: 1px 2px 2px 1px;
}

.data-cell {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
}

.data-row:hover {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ffa;
}

.data-cell::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -5000px;
  width: 10000px;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -10;
}

.data-cell:hover::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ffa;
  left: 0;
  top: -5000px;
  height: 10000px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -5;
}
```

```html
<table class="data-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="data-row">
      <td class="grey-column">I should change to hover color</td>
      <td class="data-cell">Cell 2</td>
      <td class="data-cell">Cell 3</td>
      <td class="data-cell">Cell 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="data-row">
      <td class="grey-column">I should change to hover color</td>
      <td class="data-cell">Cell 2</td>
      <td class="data-cell">Cell 3</td>
      <td class="data-cell">Cell 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="data-row">
      <td class="grey-column">I should change to hover color</td>
      <td class="data-cell">Cell 2</td>
      <td class="data-cell">Cell 3</td>
      <td class="data-cell">Cell 4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: you want the `Color me Grey`  column `grey` in color is that it.?

Comment: Let me rephrase, I want the grey column to change from grey to the hover color, upon hover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Updated***

**I think this will work for you.**

I have removed the `background` `.grey-column` and added this style.

```
.grey-column:after {
  background-color: grey;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  z-index:-20;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  content:'';
 }
 .grey-column{
  position:relative;
 }
```

working sample for you.

```css
.grey-column:after {
  background-color: grey;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  z-index:-20;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  content:'';
}
.grey-column{
 position:relative;
}

.data-table {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-width: 1px 2px 2px 1px;
}

.data-cell {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
}

.data-row:hover {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ffa;
}

.data-cell::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -5000px;
  width: 10000px;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -10;
}

.data-cell:hover::after,.grey-column:hover::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ffa;
  left: 0;
  top: -5000px;
  height: 10000px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -5;
}
```

```html
<table class="data-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="data-row">
      <td class="grey-column">I should change to hover color</td>
      <td class="data-cell">Cell 2</td>
      <td class="data-cell">Cell 3</td>
      <td class="data-cell">Cell 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="data-row">
      <td class="grey-column">I should change to hover color</td>
      <td class="data-cell">Cell 2</td>
      <td class="data-cell">Cell 3</td>
      <td class="data-cell">Cell 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="data-row">
      <td class="grey-column">I should change to hover color</td>
      <td class="data-cell">Cell 2</td>
      <td class="data-cell">Cell 3</td>
      <td class="data-cell">Cell 4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

IF there is any doubt please do ask. Hope this was helpful for you.

Comment: @JeffFasulkey, glad I could help. One more thing I have suggested an edit to your question, please consider that [*it's the ideal way to post code in stackoverflow*]

Comment: i have a followup question, is it possible to go vertical with the hover when placed over the grey column? so the entire column "i should change to hover color" is also the same as the hover color? Thank you again!

Comment: @JeffFasulkey Updated my answer please do check.